# StreamBridge with reactive binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Spring Team,

Is the [Stream bridge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_streambridge_and_dynamic_destinations) safe to use along with Kafka ***ReactiveBinder***? The below method returns a `boolean`. Not a `Mono<Boolean>`. Hence this question..!

```
streambridge.send(...)
```

The [doc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/4.0.0/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridge.html) says, it returns ***true*** if the message was sent successfully. sounds like "blocking"

Comment: No; the result simply means that the send to the target channel was successful; even with non-reactive binders (such as RabbitMQ, and the Kafka MessageChannel binder), the actual send is async. It won't block. It can only return false if the underlying channel is a type that can block, such as a `QueueChannel` with an upper bound of unprocessed messages (which is generally never the case, for any type of binder).

Comment: Thanks Gary, please add this as an answer. I assume your "No" is meant to say it is not blocking and safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

The result simply means that the send to the target channel was successful; even with non-reactive binders (such as RabbitMQ, and the Kafka MessageChannel binder), the actual send is async. It won't block.

It can only return false if the underlying channel is a type that can block, such as a QueueChannel with an upper bound of unprocessed messages (which is generally never the case, for any type of binder).